# Does the current version of msysgit support process substitution?

Tags: ipc, mingw, msysgit, msys

Under my version of msysgit, I can't use process substitution.

```
cat <(echo 'foo')
sh.exe": cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented
```

If I upgraded to the latest version of msysgit, would its version of msys / mingw be able to handle process substitution?

My current version of msysgit is 1.7.0.2.msysgit.0 and GNU bash is version 3.1.0(3)-release (i686-pc-msys).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Afraid this is still a no as of 1.7.6.msysgit.0 which has Bash 3.1.0(1).

```
bash-3.1$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.0(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
bash-3.1$ cat <(echo 'foo')
cat <(echo 'foo')
bash: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented
```

Comment: Still a no on version 1.9.2-preview20140411. Bash is 3.1.0(1).

Comment: Still a no Git-1.9.4-preview20140929, GNU bash, version 3.1.20(4)-release.

Answer (score 5):

With Git 2.5.0 also the Bash is updated:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.39(3)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

So, now your command works fine:

```
$ cat <(echo 'foo')
foo
```