# make head stop waiting for input

Tags: git, shell, sed, msysgit, head

I'm developing "custom grep" wrapper for git. It shows first line of the file matching pattern. This line expected to be the header of the file.

I've created alias and everything went OK, until I tried search for pattern, which cannot be found in the working folder. Since no files were found, `head` and `sed` commands has nothing to work with and command hands and waits for input.

How to prevent this? I would like script to interrupt if no input is given. Definitely I could create separate script, assign list of files to variable and check length of this variable. But I would prefer sweet & neat oneliner-alias.

Is it possible? Here is my `.gitconfig` alias section:

```
[alias] 
    gg = !sh -c 'head -n1 -q `git grep --name-only $0` | sed s/OBJECT.//'
```

### Resolution

Following commands for aliases worked for me on Windows 7 x64, msysGit 1.7.11.1:

```
gg = !sh -c 'head -n1 -q `git grep --name-only $0` < /dev/null | sed s/OBJECT.//'
```

and

```
gg = !sh -c 'git grep --name-only $0 | xargs -l sed -n "1{s/OBJECT.//p}"'
```

But performance was different. The first approach is noticeably more fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your immediate question on how to prevent `head` from stalling waiting for non-existent input, you can to use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) instead of command substitution:

```
head -n1 -q <(git grep --name-only $0) | sed s/OBJECT.//
```

Unlike [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) where the ```cmd``` `` portion is replace by the output of the command, with process substitution the ```<(cmd)` portion is replace by a filename of a file/pipe that contains the output of the command.

In the event where the command output is empty, `head` will still receive an input i.e. the filename of an empty file/pipe, and will proceed as you'd expect.

**P.S.** note that you will need to use `bash` instead of `sh` in order to use process substitution.

### Update

If your version of bash does not support process substitution, another way to get round the issue would be to redirect in contents from an empty or dummy file:

```
head -n1 -q `git grep --name-only $0` < /dev/null | sed s/OBJECT.//
```

Alternatively, you could simply pipe the output of  `git grep` to `xargs` which allows you to then chain in calls to `head` or `sed` as shown in [patthoyts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628838/make-head-stop-waiting-for-input/11629060#11629060).

Comment: It seems to be process substitution is not working on Windows (what I'm using now). Here is the output: `line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 0: `head -n1 -q <(git grep --name-only $0) | sed s/OBJECT.//'`

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice `sh -c`. You'll need to use `bash -c` instead in order to use process substitution.

Comment: I've switched to bash. Still not working, but error message is different: `cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented` The version of bash is following: `GNU bash, version 3.1.0(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983484/does-the-current-version-of-msysgit-support-process-substitution

Comment: @AlexeyShytikov Noted. Answer updated with alternative solution.

Comment: stream redirection from `/div/null` to `head` is missing, but if add it, everything is working.

Comment: @AlexeyShytikov Does it not work without the redirection?  `/dev/null` is a valid filename so it should be a valid input arg for `head`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need head really - sed can do that all on its own.

```
git grep --name-only $0 | sed -n "s/OBJECT.//;1p"
```

### Update

The OP is reading the first line of each file returned by git grep so:

```
git grep --name-only $0 | xargs -l sed -n "1{s/OBJECT.//;p}"
```

Comment: Does not answer question as asked by OP, but +1 nonetheless for a good solution to the actual task at hand.

Comment: Actually this is not what I need. The `grep` will pass list of file names to the `sed`. In file names given pattern will not be found. I've tried `cat`, but it combines all files to big one and I need to search on it to find headers.

Comment: Thanks, it seems getting better, but `sed` statement fails... It says something like this `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: missing command` and `p}: command not found`. Last one comes from `xargs`? Isn't it?

Comment: @patthoyts, I was able to fix my errors by deleting extra space between `1` and `{` in `sed` statement `1{s/OBJECT.//;p}`.