# Is it possible to mimic process substitution on msys /mingw (with bash 3.x)

Tags: bash, shell, mingw, msys

I am trying to use process substitution to avoid using temporary files. I tried the following:

```
diff <(echo "a") <(echo "b")
```

on mingw32/msys (from http://www.mingw.org/ as of Dec 2013), and got:

```
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Running the same thing on Ubuntu 12.04 returns:

```
1c1
< a
---
> b
```

The msys I use probably has bash 3.1. I was wondering if it is possible to work around the issue so that the same job can be done in msys/older bash without using temporary files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I mananed to do process substitution in bash 3.x. The syntax is correct. It is supported by bash shell. So I would suggest to check what shell your are running and execute somiting like:

```
/bin/bash diff <(echo "a") <(echo "b")
```

Process substitution is not a POSIX compliant feature. To enable try to run:

```
set +o posix
```

See also [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection) for more info.

The other way is to use named pipes. I tested on GNU bash version 4.1.2(1):

```
diff - p <<< "test" & echo "test2" > p
```

See Working with [Named Pipes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/085)

Comment: I got: $ /bin/bash diff <(echo "a") <(echo "b")
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: uname -a:  MINGW32_NT-5.2 DOCTOR 1.0.18(0.48/3/2) 2012-11-21 22:34 i686 Msys

Comment: I installed msys. It still does not support process substitution. See old [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983484/does-the-current-version-of-msysgit-support-process-substitution). Try to use named pipes instead. My second example works fine.

Comment: Thanks. The second command seems to work ok. Mind explaining the line a little bit? A minor issue is the input seems to hang, and I need to hit Enter to get back the bash prompt $.