# POSIX shell equivalent to <()

Tags: bash, posix, sh, zsh, process-substitution

`<(commands ...)` in bash/zsh makes the output behavior as a file.
Does a POSIX equivalent exist?

Comment: [POSIX does not specify process substitution, but you may used named pipes to accomplish the same thing.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to mimic process substitution on msys /mingw (with bash 3.x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866832/is-it-possible-to-mimic-process-substitution-on-msys-mingw-with-bash-3-x)

Comment: @P.P., I'm not really fond of that specific potential dupe, inasmuch as it folds in some misconceptions (among them, that bash 3.x *doesn't* support process substitution; that's a msys restriction, as opposed to a version-based one).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
mkfifo foo.fifo

## if your "commands" is multiple commands
# { commands ...; } >foo.fifo &

# otherwise, if it's just one
commands ... >foo.fifo &

something_else foo.fifo
```

is the closest available equivalent to

```
something_else <( commands ... )
```

Comment: Possible "robustness" improvements would be to use something like `mktemp` to generate a directory for one of more pipes safe from collisions (or just to generate a name to use for the pipe, since `mkfifo` is atomic), etc. In reality, that's all `<( ... )` is doing behind the scenes: it's just syntactic sugar for a more robust variant of this answer.

Comment: @mtraceur, that's what `<( ... )` is doing behind the scenes *on platforms where `/dev/fd` is not available*; it uses `pipe(2)` anonymous descriptor pairs where it is.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the correction - I forgot all about that.

Comment: There's no POSIX way to do this because POSIX does not define `mktemp`. One either needs to reimplement `mktemp` with using only POSIX shell behavior or have to come up with some kind of hacks.