# How can I use `< <(tail ...)` in sh, instead of bash?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I want to create a script to read a `.txt` file. This is my code:

```
while IFS= read -r lines
do
  echo "$lines"
done < <(tail -n +2 filename.txt)
```

I tried a lot of things like:

```
<<(tail -n +2 in.txt)
< < (tail -n +2 in.txt)
< (tail -n +2 in.txt)
<(tail -n +2 in.txt)
(tail -n +2 in.txt)
```

I expected to print me from the second line but instead I get an error:

```
Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Comment: It would work if you ran it with `Bash`. Process substitution is not POSIX feature.

Comment: i know that if i run it as bash it will work but i must write it in sh is there any way?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: If you don’t mind a subshell you could use `tail … | while …`.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with `tail`, and everything to do with process substitution syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to ignore the first line, there's no good reason to use `tail` at all!

```
{
    read -r first_line
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      printf '%s\n' "$line"
    done
} <filename.txt
```

Using `read` to consume the first line leaves the original file pointer intact, so following code can read directly from the file, instead of reading from a FIFO attached to the output of the `tail` program; it's thus much lower-overhead.

---

If you *did* want to use `tail`, for the specific case raised, you don't need to use a process substitution (`<(...)`), but can simply pipe into your `while` loop. Note that this has a serious side effect, insofar as any variables you set in the loop will no longer be available after it exits; this is documented (in a cross-shell manner) in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

```
tail -n +2 filename.txt | while IFS= read -r line
do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says in this answer
[POSIX shell equivalent to <()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796224/posix-shell-equivalent-to)
you could use named pipes to simulate process substitution in
POSIX. Your script would look like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

mkfifo foo.fifo

tail -n +2 filename.txt >foo.fifo &

while IFS= read -r lines
do
    echo "$lines"
done < foo.fifo

rm foo.fifo
```

Comment: How do you see this question as not being an outright duplicate of that one? It raises no questions specific to `tail`; it's simply asking the same thing (how to use process substitution in `sh`) more vaguely, without having done the homework to know the terminology.

Comment: Now when you say it I also think it's a duplicate.  I didn't think of
it as a duplicate because OP doesn't even know why his script fails,
he didn't say he has problems with process substitutions.