# Return a value set in a block within a pipeline in POSIX sh

Tags: sh

I want to log the output of a script; hence, I pipe from the block containing most of my code to tee. However, I have trouble with variables' values being lost when the pipeline exits. For example:

```
{
  (exit 3) # do something
  result=$?
} 2>&1 | tee -ia /var/log/action.log

exit "$result" # this needs to also exit with status 3
```

How do I return the value set inside the piped code block?

Comment: The curly braces aren't what destroys your value. The `|` is what destroys your value.

Comment: This issue is [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Hmm, shoot. Back when it was tagged `bash`, I could close it single-handedly. Now that it's tagged `sh`, I can't single-handedly reopen it, since I don't have a gold badge in that tag. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the curly braces, it's the pipeline. Replace it with a process substitution, and the issue goes away. In bash (as the question was initially tagged for):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT sh
{
  # do something
  result=$?
} > >(tee -ia /var/log/action.log) 2>&1

exit "$result"
```

---

Whereas with POSIX `sh`, you might end up with something more like:

```
#!/bin/sh
tempdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/myprogram.XXXXXX") || exit
mkfifo "$tempdir/fifo" || exit
tee -ia /var/log/action.log <"$tempdir/fifo" &

{
  rm -rf -- "$tempdir" # no longer needed after redirections are done
  # ...other code here...
  result=$?
} >"$tempdir/fifo" 2>&1

exit "$result"
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. Unfortunately, it was running on FreeBSD as root. bash cannot be used. :(

Comment: Tag `sh`, not `bash`, when you need a portable solution. Asking a bash question gets you a bash answer.

Comment: Notably, you can emulate process substitution in `sh` with named pipes and background processes; it's just a bit uglier. I'm pretty sure we already have an explanation of how in the knowledge base.

Comment: Here you are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796224/posix-shell-equivalent-to

Comment: Thanks Charles. You are right. I have just changed the tag.

Comment: @crackpot, g'deal. I've edited the answer to also show a concrete example of working around the issue in `sh`.