# Shell move file with renaming them

Tags: shell, find, mingw

I am using below line to copy html files from source dir to target dir. How can I rename the files while moving them to `001.html, 002.html, 003.html` etc  ?

```
find ${SourceDir} -type f -regex ".*\.\(htm\|html\|xhtm\|xhtml\)" -exec mv {} "${TargetDir}" \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a counter in a loop and use shell parameter expansion to get the file extension.

The following might work for you:

```
i=0
while read -r file; do
   fn=$(printf "%03d" $((++i)))       # get incremental numbers: 001, 002, ...
   mv "${file}" "${TargetDir}/${fn}.${file##*.}";
done < <(find ${SourceDir} -type f -regex ".*\.\(htm\|html\|xhtm\|xhtml\)")
```

---

If your shell doesn't support process substitution, you might say:

```
i=0
for file in $(find ${SourceDir} -type f -regex ".*\.\(htm\|html\|xhtm\|xhtml\)"); do
   fn=$(printf "%03d" $((++i)))       # get incremental numbers: 001, 002, ...
   mv "${file}" "${TargetDir}/${fn}.${file##*.}";
done
```

Be warned that this might not work if the filenames contain *weird* characters.

Comment: Thanks. When I use this I got 'syntax error near unexpected token `<'' error. It maybe a limitation regarding the Process Substitution, I am with MINGW32 on windows. When I try 'i=0;
find "${DECOMPILED}" -type f -regex ".*\.\(htm\|html\|xhtm\|xhtml\)" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
 fn=$(printf "%03d" $((++i)));       # get incremental numbers: 001, 002, ...
    printf '%s %s\n' "$file" "${OEBPS}/Text/${fn}.${file##*.}";
done' , then the i variable doesnt preserve its value, any other idea?

Comment: @noway It doesn't preserve the value because the loop is now running in a subshell.  Which shell are you using?

Comment: Thanks, it is bash I think. I am using the shell which comes with http://msysgit.github.io. And I have #!/bin/bash at the top of my script.

Comment: @noway Check if you are running bash in posix mode.  bash doesn't support process substitution if running in posix mode.

Comment: @noway What version of bash are you running?  Can you try saying `set +o posix` before running this?

Comment: Thanks, set +o posix did not help. I have just learned it was not possible to use it, I will find another way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983484/does-the-current-version-of-msysgit-support-process-substitution

Comment: @noway See the edit for an alternate that might work for you.